# Basic or Standard?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-elasticpool

I have only 3 databases and there is not much Data in any. I'm barely touching 400MB so size doesn't matter :) but my requirement is speed.

[image]

From the pricing, if Microsoft is persistent with scoring it seems like basic is the best choice for me since I get 100 DTUs for 900 dkk while in Standard it is only 50 DTUs for similar price.

[image]
[image]

Should I switch to basic from standard? Is there anything that they have mentioned somewhere but is not clear based on DTUs?

I've had an experience with my DB when I've had basic plan on a DB and it was really slow while it barely touched 40% of its DTU usage. :\

### Update for people seeking answer

For anyone reading this later:
Thanks to **Martins** answer I've found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu) that there is a difference in max DTUs per DB, so that you cannot have more than 5 eDTUs per Database!!!! Which makes it useless for production environment! :\

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **depends** on your requirement. Standard has more features then Basic (e. g. increased point in time restore, more concurrent users, etc...).

You may consider switching to [vCore-based purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-vcore) in order to independently scale compute and storage resources.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've just found another difference on docs that you've shared (DTU based). It says max eDTUs per DB is only 5 in basic plan :|